# Why use Magic Weapon and Familiar over Storm Armor

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

So I've chosen to disable electives with my Wizard, and found MW, Familiar, and SA to be in the same category. I don't have all the runes unlocked but I am finding SA to be far better that the other two due to the massive difference in damage.

So for what reason would I ever use MW or Familiar when they do around 20%, while SA does 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Magic weapon and Sparkflint both boost overall DPS of everything, where storm armor only provides 100% weapon damage to enemies in the area.  If your wizard relies on other methods of killing, such as archon form or wicked wind, then MW and Sparkflint provides more benefit.  Also, a lot of wizards like to run with energy armor for survivability anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I belive Magic Weapon and Sparkflint are very very important for Wizards using Hungering Arrow and Arcane Orb. Armor should be used as... Armor, I guess?...
I use Energy Armor, of course.
But, as much as I have this option, I think that Critical Mass / freeze everything builds are perhaps more efective.
This to say that these two options seem to be the only viable ones these days... Wizard is weak - unless loaded with tons of expensive gear. Be as it might be you need to really be a good player to be able to go through high MP with Wiz, gear is important, yes, but personal skills seem to be an even more important requirement.

Comment: wizard is hardly weak.  you can easily throw together a fast mp3 farming archon wizard for 10m